# How do I fix this ability.rb precedence issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, ruby-on-rails-5, cancancan

I am using CanCanCan and in my `ability.rb` file I have this:

```
  def initialize(user)
    alias_action :vote_up, :vote_down, to: :vote

    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :manage, Question, user_id: user.id
      can :manage, Answer, user_id: user.id
      can :manage, Job, user_id: user.id
      can :manage, Company, user_id: user.id
      can :read, :all
      cannot :read, User do |u|
        !u.eql?(user.id)
      end

      can :vote, [Question, Answer]

    end
end
```

However, when I try to vote with a user that doesn't own a `question`, it rejects it.

For instance, when I am logged in as `abc@test.com`, this is what the log looks like on a vote:

```
Started POST "/questions/yet-another-hello-world/vote_up" for ::1 at 2016-06-14 23:45:13 -0500
Processing by QuestionsController#vote_up as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"yet-another-hello-world"}
  User Load (2.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1546], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Question Load (4.8ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."user_id" = $1 AND "questions"."slug" = $2 ORDER BY "questions"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 1546], ["slug", "yet-another-hello-world"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Answer Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = 43
   (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2 AND "votes"."voter_id" = $3 AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL AND "votes"."voter_type" = $4  [["votable_id", 43], ["votable_type", "Question"], ["voter_id", 1546], ["voter_type", "User"]]
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (3.8ms)  INSERT INTO "votes" ("votable_type", "votable_id", "voter_type", "voter_id", "vote_flag", "vote_weight", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["votable_type", "Question"], ["votable_id", 43], ["voter_type", "User"], ["voter_id", 1546], ["vote_flag", true], ["vote_weight", 1], ["created_at", 2016-06-15 04:45:13 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-06-15 04:45:13 UTC]]
   (0.9ms)  COMMIT
   (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2 AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 43], ["votable_type", "Question"]]
   (1.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2 AND "votes"."vote_flag" = $3 AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 43], ["votable_type", "Question"], ["vote_flag", true]]
   (1.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2 AND "votes"."vote_flag" = $3 AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 43], ["votable_type", "Question"], ["vote_flag", false]]
   (1.6ms)  SELECT SUM("votes"."vote_weight") FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2 AND "votes"."vote_flag" = $3 AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 43], ["votable_type", "Question"], ["vote_flag", true]]
   (1.5ms)  SELECT SUM("votes"."vote_weight") FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2 AND "votes"."vote_flag" = $3 AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 43], ["votable_type", "Question"], ["vote_flag", false]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT SUM("votes"."vote_weight") FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2 AND "votes"."vote_flag" = $3 AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 43], ["votable_type", "Question"], ["vote_flag", true]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT SUM("votes"."vote_weight") FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2 AND "votes"."vote_flag" = $3 AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["votable_id", 43], ["votable_type", "Question"], ["vote_flag", false]]
   (0.8ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (2.1ms)  UPDATE "questions" SET "cached_votes_total" = $1, "cached_votes_up" = $2, "cached_votes_score" = $3, "cached_weighted_total" = $4, "cached_weighted_score" = $5, "updated_at" = $6 WHERE "questions"."id" = $7  [["cached_votes_total", 1], ["cached_votes_up", 1], ["cached_votes_score", 1], ["cached_weighted_total", 1], ["cached_weighted_score", 1], ["updated_at", 2016-06-15 04:45:13 UTC], ["id", 43]]
   (1.5ms)  COMMIT
  Rendering questions/vote_up.js.erb
  Rendered questions/vote_up.js.erb (1.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 69ms (Views: 14.8ms | ActiveRecord: 26.9ms)
```

Which is normal and works wonderfully.

However, if I login as another user and try to vote_up that same question, this is what the log looks like:

```
Started POST "/questions/yet-another-hello-world/vote_up" for ::1 at 2016-06-14 23:46:40 -0500
Processing by QuestionsController#vote_up as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"yet-another-hello-world"}
  User Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1547], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Question Load (3.2ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."user_id" = $1 AND "questions"."slug" = $2 ORDER BY "questions"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 1547], ["slug", "yet-another-hello-world"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 5.3ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
  friendly_id (5.1.0) lib/friendly_id/finder_methods.rb:23:in `find'
  app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:123:in `set_question'
```

You can see that it is checking if the question belongs to the `current_user` in my controller but it fails here:

```
def set_question
  @question = current_user.questions.includes(:answers).friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

Thoughts?

Comment: It may be helpful to add your `questions_controller.rb` snippet here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@question = current_user.questions.includes(:answers).friendly.find(params[:id])
```

This is where went wrong, since `current_user` doesn't own the question, the question couldn't be found with both `question_id` and `user_id`. You could see what the query does in the log:

> SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."user_id" =
>   $1 AND "questions"."slug" = $2 ORDER BY "questions"."id" ASC LIMIT $3 
>   [["user_id", 1547], ["slug", "yet-another-hello-world"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

Change the finding question query to this:

```
@question = Question.includes(:answers).friendly.find(params[:id])
```

Now all users could vote the question even if the question is not owned by him/her.

Comment: Perfect. This was exactly the issue. Thanks much!